# Validate dynamic checkbox

Tags: html, checkbox, coldfusion

I have two tables in the database, Table A and Table B. User fill up Form A that will insert new record in Table A. In Form B, the records in Table A are called as checkbox. From this form, the data will be inserted into Table B. The following code are in Form B. The data captured in this code will be inserted into a column (let say column name is menu_check), resulting something like "value1,value2,value3" (depending on how many checkbox the user check)

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chckmenu" id="chckmenu" value="#qMenu.menu_id#"   />#qMenu.menu_name_eng#
```

After Form B is complete, user will be directed to a page where shows the list of all records in Table B. From this table, user can edit any records. Something like a simple listing where the user can view, update or delete any records. In the edit page, how to call out the value of menu_check, and see if any checkbox are checked or not based on the column.

For example:

- If value in menu_check is 'value1,value2,value3', only the first, second and third checkbox are checked.
- If value in menu_check is 'value1,value3', only first and third checkbox are checked.

I tried using delimiters but still can't get it as I don't know where to proceed after this.

```
<cfloop delimiter="," index="a" list="#queryname.menu_check#"></cfloop>
```

I try using something like;

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chckmenu" id="chckmenu" value="#qMenu.menu_id#" <cfif "#queryname.menu_check#" EQ "#qMenu.menu_id#">selected</cfif> /> #qMenu.menu_name_eng#
```

But that also didn't work. I'm using ColdFusion9.

Comment: This is all nice. What have you tried so far to make this work?

Comment: @James A Mohler I tried <cfloop delimiter="," index="a" list="queryname.menu_check"></cfloop> to get the values without the comma, but i have no idea on validating them. I have also tried <cfif #qMenu.menu_id# EQ "#queryname.menu_check#"> checked </cfif>. But it doesn't work.

Comment: You need to add that type of information to the question. You may also want to add a screen shot of a dump of your query and a screenshot of what results your got. It would also be useful to know what version of CF you are using.

Comment: Noted. Added more details in my question.

Comment: `.. data captured in this code will be inserted into a column ... resulting something like "value1,value2,value3"` Might want to reconsider your table design. While the current problem can be solved with list functions, it's usually a bad idea to store lists in a db. Lists are a lot more difficult to query and/or manipulate.

Comment: @Ageax I choose this because the checkbox are dynamic. There could be a lot of checkbox in the future. In terms of database design, I'm a novice. Any advice?

Comment: @jdow - The usual pattern for storing a many-to-many relationship is three tables. Say the form is for selecting customer preferences, you'd have 3 tables: "Customer", "Preference" (all possible preferences), "CustomerPreference" (selected preferences per customer). Each selection is stored as a separate row in the 3rd table. That way you can store as few or as many preferences as needed, and change them easily. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3b2f78/2/0

Comment: @jdow - I added a full example below to demonstrate what a normalized structure looks like and how it works. Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve this problem. I am using CONTAIN to check whether the value exist in the database. My line of code;

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chckmenu" id="chckmenu" value="#qMenu.menu_id#"  
<cfif qSubCheck.con_check CONTAINS #qMenu.menu_id#>Checked</cfif>
/>#qMenu.menu_name_eng#
```

Thank you all for your help!

Comment: If you are working with lists, don't use CONTAINS. Unlike list functions, CONTAINS doesn't match whole values.  So a search for "value1" would also match "value11" and "value1111". Though again, I would not recommend storing list in a database table. Also, nothing to do with the question, but no need for pound signs in the cfif.

Comment: ... in other words, CONTAINS may return the wrong result for lists.

Comment: Noted. I'll keep a mental note on your advice. So far my function is just to find value 1, 2, 3 and 4 in the database table, so it should be fine for now. Thanks again.

Comment: Since it is a simple change, I'd fix it now... to avoid creating future bugs when I've long since forgotten the issue ... but that is just me ;-)

Answer (score 1):

For making `input[type=checkbox]` checked, you need to use `checked` not `selected`.

Since the value for `queryname.menu_check` you can use [`listFind(list, value [, delimiters, includeEmptyValues])`](https://cfdocs.org/listfind) function for checking if the value is present in `queryname.menu_check`.

```
<cfset checkedstatus = "">
<cfif ListFind(queryname.menu_check, qMenu.menu_id)>
  <cfset checkedstatus = " checked">
</cfif>
<input type="checkbox" name="chckmenu" id="chckmenu" value="#qMenu.menu_id#"#checkedstatus#/> #qMenu.menu_name_eng#
```

In loop

```
<cfoutput query="qMenu">
  <cfset checkedstatus = "">
  <cfif ListFind(queryname.menu_check, qMenu.menu_id)>
    <cfset checkedstatus = " checked">
  </cfif>
  <input type="checkbox" name="chckmenu" id="chckmenu" value="#qMenu.menu_id#"#checkedstatus#/> #qMenu.menu_name_eng#
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Thanks! But when I tried this with cfloop (because I need to loop the checkbox), all the checkbox are checked if at least one value are in the table. Let say I checked the first checkbox, when editing it, all checkbox are checked instead of the first checkbox only.

Comment: You just need to do one thing. In the start of each iteration `<cfset checkedstatus = "">` this needs to be there. _ie._ The whole code snippet in my answer needs to be inside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on [RRK's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49007779/8895292), lists (and list functions) certainly help. However, I wouldn't recommend actually storing data in the database that way. Instead, [use a junction or bridge table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity), which provides greater flexibility and performance than lists.

[Sample Table Structure](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c5061e/1/0)

- User - *Table of unique users*
- Menu - *Table of unique menu options*
- UserMenu - *Table of selected menu options for each user*

Notice, the junction table stores each selection as a separate row. That way you can store as few or as many selections as needed, and change them easily.

Using that structure, the edit page just retrieves the selected options for the current user and converts those values into a list.

```
 <cfquery name="qSelectedOptions" ...>
     SELECT MenuId
     FROM   UserMenu 
     WHERE  UserId = <cfqueryparam value="#form.currentUserID#" .... >
 </cfquery>

 <cfset selectedOptions = valueList(qSelectedOptions.MenuId)>
```

Then inside the loop generating the checkboxes, a simple list function determines whether each box should be checked:

```
 <cfquery name="qMenu" ...>
     SELECT MenuId, MenuName
     FROM   Menu
     ORDER BY MenuName
 </cfquery>

 <cfoutput query="qMenu">
     #MenuName# 
     <input type="checkbox" name="menuOptions" value="#MenuId#" 
         <cfif listFind(selectedOptions, menuId)>checked</cfif>>
 </cfoutput>
```

Finally, to save the selections to the database, first DELETE the existing values, then INSERT any new ones.

```
   <cftransaction>
       <cfquery ....>
         DELETE FROM UserMenu 
         WHERE  UserId = <cfqueryparam value="#form.currentUserID#" cfsqltype="...">
       </cfquery ....>
       <cfquery ....>
          INSERT INTO UserMenu (UserID, MenuID)
          SELECT <cfqueryparam value="#form.currentUserID#" cfsqltype="...">
                     , MenuId
          FROM   Menu
          WHERE  MenuId IN (
             <cfqueryparam value="#form.menuOptions#" list cfsqltype="...">

          )
       </cfquery>
    </cftransaction>
```